# Why this SQL does not work in python

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

```
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM `productinfo` WHERE CreateDate > '%s'",kakko)
```

where `kakko` is user input string, for example, 2012-01-15

'%s' is not correct?

Comment: I may be misremembering, but cursor.execute may require a parameter tuple. Try `cur.execute("SELECT * FROM \`productinfo\` WHERE CreateDate > '%s'", (kakko, ))`... In addition I'm not sure which parameter quoting style you're supposed to use with MySQLdb, so try ? instead of %s, too.

Comment: @AKX use `%s` and post that as answer - as you're right

Comment: You also don't need any quotation marks around the `%s`.

Comment: @Tim : Thanks, I need the quotation marks because I have to compare the date in SQL.

Answer (score 1):

So, elaborating from the comments:

`cursor.execute` requires a parameter tuple, and you don't need to quote the `%s`:

```
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM `productinfo` WHERE CreateDate > %s", (kakko, ))
```